# Divs jitter when hovering between them quickly

Tags: html, css

I have the following html code:

```
<div class="project">
    <h3 class="black product">Dash</h3>
    <a href="#" class="black hide">view project</a>
</div>
<div class="project">
    <h3 class="black product">5/3/1</h3>
    <a href="#" class="black hide">view project</a>
</div>
```

and the following css code:

```
.hide {
    display: none;
}

div.project:hover h3{
    line-height: 200px;
}

div.project:hover .hide {
    display: inline-block;
}

div.project {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 2px solid #222;
    margin: 0px 20px 20px 20px;
}

h3.product { font-size: 24px; line-height: 300px;}
```

Which is basically just two div buttons side by side. When I hover over each div the product title moves up and the "view product" text appears.

However when I quickly hover between the two divs they "jitter" up and down, and stay "jittered". From what I have seen, this occurs in Safari but not in Chrome.

http://jsfiddle.net/f8Laktoz/ Here is the jsfiddle.

This is my first time asking a question, so let me know if I can be more specific. Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not been able to reproduce in firefox either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its seems to be a bug with the way the divs are 'displacing' each other on hover.

Try adding this to your css:

```
div.project {
  ...
  float: left;
}
```

Working JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f8Laktoz/1/

Comment: Works great thanks. It screwed up my centering though, so I put everything in a wrapper div and put display: inline-block and text-align: center to center the two divs.